# Tunnel and Bubble events in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have follwing grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
```

I want to handle MouseDown and MouseUp events both at Grid and Button level. How to do that?

Comment: Isn't this question a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709794/event-firing-problem-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this a continuation from your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709794/event-firing-problem-in-wpf).

A `Button` control will swallow mouse events, so they won't bubble up through the hierarchy to the grid. If there is common functionality for both the grids mousedown and mouseup events and the button, then I'd suggest methodising it and calling it from their own respective handlers.

Hope it helps - Val